# Xpath для чекбоксов

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Есть [страничка](https://market.yandex.ru/catalog/58612/list?hid=237418&track=fr_ctlg&onstock=1&local-offers-first=0), в которой есть чек боксы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо выделить один из чек боксов:

```
public class MainCkass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium test\\geckodriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://market.yandex.ru/catalog/58612/list?hid=237418&track=fr_ctlg&onstock=1&local-offers-first=0");
    List<WebElement> checkboxes =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = \"_178jz2CyDL\"]/div[4]//input[@type=\"checkbox\"]"));
    checkboxes.get(4).click();
```

В итоге не выходит, может `Xpath` не правильный?

Answer (score 0):

xpath рабочий, но по-крайней мере сейчас возвращает не тот блок с чекбоксами, что указан на скриншоте (возможно влияние выбранного региона на остатки и фильтры со значениями), из-за чего в моём случае клик происходил бы по некликабельному чекбоксу из-за наличия у оного атрибута `disabled`.
Советы по решению:

1. Лучше привести xpath в более читаемый и надёжный вид:

   `//legend[contains(text(), 'Производитель')]//following-sibling::node()[1]//input[@type='checkbox']`

да, на текст желательно не завязываться, но текущий DOM не оставляет иного читаемого выбора решения.

2. Вы запрашиваете чекбоксы сразу после изменения ширины браузера: в теории, есть вероятность, что при первоначальной отрисовке со стандартной шириной браузера, взятой из конфигурации, применились стили для мобильной версии, на которой не отображены чекбоксы на форме, и вы пытаетесь получить чекбоксы, которые ещё не успели подтянуться после применения maximize-ширины. Попробуйте перед запросом получения чекбоксов удостовериться, что чекбоксы действительно отрисованы.
3. Точно ли пытаетесь кликнуть по чекбоксу, который действительно существует, и который действительно является кликабельным для пользователя? Попробуйте вручную или/и автоматически прокликать по прочим чекбоксам из данной группы чекбоксов.